# vue.js How to get Label from selected Radio Button to show in Preview

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a form built with bootstrap-vue. The form contains some Radio buttons. I do have a preview button which should show what was selected, but instead of the value from the radio button I would like the label. The radio button code looks something like this:

```
  <b-form-group label="Location">
  <b-form-radio-group
    v-model="selectedLocation"
    :options="options"
    :aria-describedby="ariaDescribedby"
    name="radio-inline"
  ></b-form-radio-group>
  </b-form-group>

  <b-button variant="primary" @click="handlePreview()"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Preview</b-button>
```

My script looks something like below:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedLocation: '1',

    options: [
      { text: 'Location1', value: '1' },
      { text: 'Location2', value: '2' },
      { text: 'Location3', value: '4' }
    ],
```

},

```
methods: {

  handlePreview(){ 
    this.preview = true;
    this.selectedLocationText = this.selectedLocation.text
    console.log(this.selectedLocationText); 
  },
```

Is that easily possible to get the Text shown in my Preview? I just cant figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
this.selectedLocationText = this.options.find(option => option.value === this.selectedLocation)
```

But remember to define selectedLocationText inside `data()`

Comment: It was that easy. Thank you so much. I was thinking far too complicated as usual and that got me nowhere. So just for everyone else console.log("Location " +this.selectedLocationText.text);  you have to add .text otherwise you get Object Object of course but specially beginners might not know. Thank you very much again for your quick response !